# Sending Outlook ical message with html table

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I've been working on a simple HTML form that will ask the user for info and when submitted, will have a PHP script email certain people with a calendar invite.

I also want the body of this calendar invite to have an HTML body - with an HTML table included.

With the code below I am able to send the email using PHP's mail function and it generates the appointment.  I can also add HTML content however the **table gets stripped away.**

I've read somewhere that the calendar invite only supports RTF.  This may be true however I've noticed on an OWA account the table does not get stripped away.

Can someone shed some light on my dilemma?  Thanks!

```
function sendIcalEmail($htmlmsg,$email,$meeting_date,$s_ccemail) {
```

```
$from_name = "sender name"
$from_address = "sender email"
$subject = "Test Appointment"; //Doubles as email subject and meeting subject in calendar
$meeting_description = "Description"    


//Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
$meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date . " EST");    
$dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp);
$dtend= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp+7200);
$todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z");

//Create unique identifier
$cal_uid = date("Ymd")."T".date("His")."-".rand()."@mydomain.com";

//Create Mime Boundry
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".md5(time());

//Create Email Headers
$headers = "From: Sender Name <noreply@domain.com>" . "\n";
$headers .= "Cc: ". $s_ccemail . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@domain.com" . "\n";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";

$message .= $htmlmsg . "\r\n";

$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
```

```
$ical = "
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:".$from_address."
DTSTART:".$dtstart."
DTEND:".$dtend."
LOCATION:
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:".$cal_uid."
DTSTAMP:".$todaystamp."
DESCRIPTION:".$meeting_description."
SUMMARY:".$subject."
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";
```

`$message .= "Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

//SEND MAIL
$mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

if($mail_sent)     
{
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, but for me it was outlook 2003 would accept some formats, outlook 2007 would accept others, and go figure outlook 2010 accepted even others still.  I was able to get a working ICAL from php and posted it on the [ExchangeCore Forums](http://forums.exchangecore.com/topic/908-using-php-to-send-ical-events/)

Hopefully this will help you.